# What is meaning of dyadic compactness?

Tags: general-topology, terminology

What is meaning of dyadic compact space? Is it as the same as Cantor cube $D^\kappa$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to Engelking (p.231), a *dyadic space* is a compact space which is a  continuous image of a Cantor cube $D^\kappa$.  (See also the [Encyclopedia of Mathematics](https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Dyadic_compactum).)